# Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension for rails version 5.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I cloned a ruby on rails app and try to run **bundle install** here is the full error what i got while running the app :

> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
C:/Ruby22/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
generating generator-i386-mingw32.def
compiling generator.c
In file included from c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
                 from generator.c:1:
c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:118:14: error: size of array 'ruby_check_sizeof_voidp' is negative
In file included from c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
                 from generator.c:1:
c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_obj_freeze_inline':
c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1171:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1172:2: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1173:6: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1173:27: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_data_object_get':
c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1207:13: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_obj_written':
c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1286:10: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1286:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_num2char_inline':
c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1359:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1359:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1359:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1359:36: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1359:36: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1359:36: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1360:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1360:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1360:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_class_of':
c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1685:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_type':
c:/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1702:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
In file included from generator.c:1:0:
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h: In function 'fbuffer_append_str':
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:127:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:127:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:127:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'convert_UTF8_to_JSON_ASCII':
generator.c:135:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:135:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:135:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:136:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:136:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:136:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'convert_UTF8_to_JSON':
generator.c:233:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:233:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:233:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:234:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:234:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:234:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_configure':
generator.c:572:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:572:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:572:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:573:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:573:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:573:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:580:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:580:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:580:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:581:33: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:581:33: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:581:33: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:588:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:588:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:588:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:589:40: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:589:40: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:589:40: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:596:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:596:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:596:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:597:36: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:597:36: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:597:36: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:604:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:604:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:604:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:605:37: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:605:37: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:605:37: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'set_state_ivars':
generator.c:653:21: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:653:21: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:653:21: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:655:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:655:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:655:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'generate_json_object':
generator.c:740:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:740:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:740:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'generate_json_array':
generator.c:786:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:786:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:786:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'generate_json':
generator.c:892:16: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:892:16: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:892:16: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'isArrayOrObject':
generator.c:953:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:953:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:953:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:954:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:954:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:954:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_indent_set':
generator.c:1078:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1078:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1078:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1087:32: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1087:32: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1087:32: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_space_set':
generator.c:1116:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1116:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1116:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1125:31: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1125:31: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1125:31: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_space_before_set':
generator.c:1152:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1152:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1152:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1161:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1161:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1161:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_object_nl_set':
generator.c:1190:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1190:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1190:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1198:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1198:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1198:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_array_nl_set':
generator.c:1225:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1225:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1225:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1233:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1233:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1233:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

I tried a lot to solve this error but after every try getting same error.

Comment: Which devkit ruby are you trying to install? can you point your selection from https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ ?

Comment: i used this DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe

Comment: are you sure your system is 64 bit? According to error trace, it's trying to find in i386 which usually correspond to 32 bit system. Try 32 bit binary maybe - https://dl.bintray.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx.exe

Comment: yes its 64 bit i just checked it from my computer property.

Comment: I can be wrong about how ruby installer and devkits work on Windows, but I think devkit is correlated with which the version of ruby installed in your system. If you are trying to install ruby for the first time, you should try the with-devkit installer from the top - https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/releases/download/rubyinstaller-2.4.4-1/rubyinstaller-devkit-2.4.4-1-x64.exe

Comment: Development kit(old) will allow you to get ruby development working with ruby 2.0-2.3 already installed in your system.